# Spring JMS Publish/Susbcriber configuration to IBM Webpshere MQ

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

Searching in the web I found a lot of example of how spring have to be configured (file.xml) for publish/subscriber mode for active MQ but I need how beans need to be configured for Websphere MQ
Anyone have been configured both product with success?

Answer (score 2):

The following is bean definition of a Websphere MQ `ConnectionFactory`:

```
<bean id="wmqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="queueManager">
        <value>QUEUE_MANAGER</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hostName">
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="port">
        <value>1414</value>
    </property>
    <property name="transportType">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="channel">
        <value>SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

you may need to provide a username and password, and you can accomplish that by wrapping it in a [`UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.html):

```
<bean id="userCredentialsAdapter" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="wmqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value=" " />
    <property name="password" value=" " />
</bean>
```

It is also a good idea to wrap it in a [`CachingConnectionFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html), so that sessions, consumers and producers are cached, this wrapper also switches the auto-recovery to true:

```
<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="userCredentialsAdapter"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
</bean>
```

with this configuration, you can use the `cachingConnectionFactory` with whatever bean you need.